# Using a ternary operator to fill a SqlCommand parameter

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I need to fill a parameter in a `SqlCommand`, but for some conditions I want to fill it with `DBNull.Value` and otherwise with a value.

What I need is that when the variable `truckID == -1` then put `DBNull.Value` in the parameter, else put the value of `truckID` in it.

This is what I have tried:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString()))
{
   command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TruckID", truckID == -1 ? DBNull.Value : truckID);
```

but the compiler tells me :

> Error CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'int'

If I would write this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TruckID", truckID == -1 ? 0 : truckID);
```

then the compiler is happy. So it seems that for a ternary operator both possible values must be of the same type.

What would be the best way to do this ?

**EDIT:**

the working code for me is this :

```
command.Parameters.Add
    (new SqlParameter("@TruckID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (import.TruckID == -1) ? (object)DBNull.Value : import.TruckID);
```

**EDIT:**
Actually the code above did not work after all.
At runtime I got this :

> SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type
>   objects, not DBNull objects

So I modified the code to this and that finally worked for me.

```
command.Parameters.Add
    (new SqlParameter("@PlaceID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = (import.TruckID == -1) ? (object)DBNull.Value : import.TruckID });
```

Comment: Is a regular ol' `if` statement such a bad idea here?

Comment: They must be the same type or implicitly convert (IIRC). Just split it into actual if statements.

Comment: `truckId == -1 ? (object) DBNull.value : truckID`. And don't use [`.AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Why is AddWithValue not good to use ?

Comment: Click the link.

Comment: @JeroenMostert OK thanks I did not knew this

Comment: This is just *yet another* reason why you should **avoid** using `AddWithValue`! You should also check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@truckID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
param.Value = (truckID == -1) ? DBNull.Value : truckID;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Well one liner version would be

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@truckID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) 
                          { Value = (truckID == -1) ? (object)DBNull.Value : truckID };
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Another version:

```
SqlParameter param = (truckID == -1) ? 
                       new SqlParameter("@truckID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) { Value = DBNull.Value } 
                      : new SqlParameter("@truckID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) { Value = truckID };
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Yes but I want to keep it on one line of code

Comment: OK that is what I need thanks I just put the first line as parameter for the parameters.add()

Comment: @GuidoG Did this work? It should have the same problem you originally had and additionally the one liner version looks very odd to me. That shouldn't compile. It should be something like this: `SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@truckID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) { Value = (truckID == -1) ? (object)DBNull.Value : truckID };

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Yes I had to adapt the code a little to make it compile but the idea does works. I just edited the question and put the working one liner at the bottom

Comment: @RomanoZumbé The code did not work at runtime after all. Check the last edit in my question I have changed the code again and now it really worked

Comment: @GuidoG Thats what I expected. The code in this example simply can't compile

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, you didn't seen my edit .. now it will compile fine. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: @Rahul Absolutely not! `SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@truckID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = (truckID == -1) ? (object)DBNull.Value : truckID;`. You can't access `Value` that way!

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, hmm, missed it. anyway corrected now and as there is another one liner version.

Answer (score 2):

You could explicitly cast `DBNull.Value` to object:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TruckID", truckID == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : truckID);
```